# Expand git repo

Tags: git

I've got some code that looks like this on the file system:

```
1.java
A/a.java
```

The code in `A` is contained in a git repo.

However, I now want to expand the repo to cover the **entire** code base (i.e. including 1.java which is 1 directory up).

I've got a feeling (having played around with submodules) that it's not as easy as just `init`'ing a git repo in the parent directory. Am I right? If so, how should I tackle this?

Answer (score 5):

```
cd A
mkdir A
git mv -k * A/
git commit -m "Expand git repo"
cd ..
mv A tmpA
mv tmpA/{.git,A} ./
rmdir tmpA
```

In other words, do the reorg inside the repo, then just move everything up a directory. Git won't know the difference because all of the filenames will match.

The `mv -k` stops git from trying to move `A/` into itself, which would be an error.